# Directing multiple domains to one server

Tags: domain

I would like to host 5 word-press blogs on my unlimited server space i bought from a web-hosting company similar to hostgator.

Now the companies say it is technically not possible to direct more than one domain to the hosting package and i would need to buy multiple hosting packages .

I read about vhost (apache),domain alias,ip forwarding

But not sure how ask my webhost about it when they say it is not possible

here is what i want to do

xhost.com/folder1  << www.x.com
xhost.com/folder2  << www.y.com
xhost.com/folder3  << www.z.com
xhost.com/folder4  << www.aa.com

the web host has a cpanel so dont know if they give/have access to vhosts if they are a reseller

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

While Technically possible this may be an arbitrary limitation of your provider to increase revenue.

This is really a question for the host, if you want the technical information to actually set up your own server then you are in the right place. Unfortunately we can't usually help too much with provider specific issues. Without full access to the server and Apache config I doubt you would have much luck implementing this.

As to asking the host, you are correct, vhosts is the tech you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can point as many domain names as you like to a single IP address. HTTP 1.0+ adds a `Host` header to the request so that the server can distinguish which of the domain names is being requested.

What you cannot do is have other services such as FTP, SSH, etc. use different domain names on the same IP address since they do not send something that the server can use to determine which domain name is being requested.